# Building JPA query with "and" and same column names

Tags: java, jpa, dynamic

I have an entity Offers and I need to build named query on combination of two field.

Fields  pr_id and of_id.

So the actual query would look like

```
 Select pr_id, of_id, a, b from Offers 
  where ( (pr_id=1 and of_id=2) 
     or   (pr_id=2 and of_id=1)
     or  (pr_id=1 and of_id=2))
```

The "and" increases based on other result. Max 10. But it doesn't matter for this question. Values are parameters obviously.

I need to call a library method

```
    findByNamedQuery( QueryName, Map<String, Object>)   or 
    findByQuery(query)
```

Can't change the above methods.
If I use the first one, I am not sure how it works if the field names and dynamic parameter names repeat in the query with JPA.

So for instance with JPA, it would look like this:

```
    map("pr_id",":pr_id");
    map("of_id",":of_id");
    map("pr_id",":pr_id");
    map("of_id",":of_id");
    map("pr_id",":pr_id");
    map("of_id",":of_id");
```

So I guess I have only the 2nd option? Build the query with actual values dynamically exactly like the actual query.

Any idea how to use the 1st one?

Comment: ...I think you mean to join your parenthesised expressions with OR, not AND. As your query is currently written, that condition will never match.

Comment: The numbers I entered above are random. But thats what I need. Need to check any records for the combination exists. Question is how to build the Map of parameters for it

Comment: You've still missed my point, which is: `a = 1 AND a = 2 AND a = 3` is guaranteed to be false; `a` cannot be 1, 2, and 3 at the same time. If you want to see if `a` is 1, 2, or 3, you could say `a = 1 OR a = 2 OR a = 3`, or `a IN (1, 2, 3)` or (for contiguous numbers) `a BETWEEN 1 AND 3`.

Comment: ah. I got your point. yes, thats how it should. late night entry :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you going to build the query? The question is about how to populate the parameter map, but that depends on how you name the parameters in the query. You must have a different parameter name for each different value that you are looking for.

As I understand that the number of "OR" conditions is variable, you cannot use named queries, which are static, therefore you couldn't use the findByNamedQuery method.

You can dynamically build the query string with JPQL:

```
SELECT pr_id, of_id, a, b FROM Offers 
WHERE((pr_id=:pr_id_1 and of_id=:of_id_1) 
 OR   (pr_id=:pr_id_2 and of_id=:of_id_2)
 OR   (pr_id=:pr_id_3 and of_id=:of_id_3))
```

And then pass each parameter:

```
...
query.setParameter(pr_id_1, 4534);
query.setParameter(pr_id_2, 6368);
query.setParameter(pr_id_3, 2345);
...
```

Or you can use Criteria API to build dynamic queries in a type-safe way